# How to make a responsive grid in python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, game-development

I am trying to create a coloured grid in tkinter such that when I click on any particular part of the grid it changes colour.

An example of how the grid looks like is below with the code -

[image]

Code -

```py
def draw_board(canvas):
    for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
        for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
            x0, y0 = i * SQUARE_SIZE, j * SQUARE_SIZE
            x1, y1 = x0 + SQUARE_SIZE, y0 + SQUARE_SIZE
            color_grid = [[random.choice(COLORS) for j in range(GRID_SIZE)] for i in range(GRID_SIZE)] # COLORS = ["green", "yellow"]
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color_grid[i][j])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event handler to a given `Canvas` item with `tag_bind()` like so

```
def on_click(event):  # event handler function
    item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    canvas.itemconfig(item, fill='#FF3344')  # set new fill color


def draw_board(canvas):
    for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
        for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
            x0, y0 = i * SQUARE_SIZE, j * SQUARE_SIZE
            x1, y1 = x0 + SQUARE_SIZE, y0 + SQUARE_SIZE
            color_grid = [[random.choice(COLORS) for j in range(GRID_SIZE)] for i in range(GRID_SIZE)] # COLORS = ["green", "yellow"]
            rect = canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color_grid[i][j])
            canvas.tag_bind(rect, '<Button>', on_click)  # bind the event handler function
```

Comment: Also, is there anyway for me to get the exact location of the click in terms of list indices? For example, a tuple like ```(12,9)``` ?

Comment: If you want pixel coordinates, the `on_click` function can get those as `event.x` and `event.y` (I'm already doing this in the call to `find_closest`). Otherwise, if you just want access to the rect that was clicked, you have that through `item`. Getting something like (row, column) is a bit trickier. You could add these values as "tags" for each rectangle: `rect = canvas.create_rectangle(..., tags=[(i, j)])`, then parse them out of `self.canvas.itemcget(item, 'tags')` inside `on_click` (it's not a perfect solution, but the i and j values should be in the string of tags you get from that)